# new PDO refuses to work

Tags: php, pdo

I want to create a sqlite database with these lines:

```
<?php
echo "here<br/>";

try {
  $db_connection = new PDO('sqlite:file.db');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "there<br/>";
?>
```

After that I expect the output

```
here
there
```

and the file `file.db` to exist in the folder.

But I only see `here`and there is no file. So it seems like `new` fails without even throwing an exception.

Here is what I checked so far:

- php version is 5.4.16
- folder is writable for apache (in fact, permissions are 777)

What else could be/is the problem?

**edit**

I also tried this following felipsmartins answer:

```
$ php -i | grep -i sqlite
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
PDO drivers => sqlite
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.7.17
sqlite3
SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7
SQLite Library => 3.7.17
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value
```

But `phpinfo()` does not show any `PDO` or `sqlite` entries.

Comment: This is because your PDO driver is not installed

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ: According to https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php, the sqlite driver is enabled by default. But you are right. the test in the link you gave says "driver unavailable". Please make this an answer.

Comment: + from me for descriptive question

Comment: any progress so far?

Comment: no, it seems to be a corrupted or incomplete installation. And the admins are busy, so I ended up writing a csv instead of using sqlite...

Comment: what a sad thing, but I will stick to the idea of using driver checker in code, this will ensure driver availability. good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4):

As specified in the PHP [documentaion](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php), PDO expects an absolute pathname on DSN string:

> To access a database on disk, append the **absolute** path to the DSN
>   prefix.

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:' . __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'file.db');
```

And, of course, make sure you have SQLite support enabled. Take a look on the quick command: `php -i | grep -i sqlite`

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have SQLite support enabled: `php -i | grep -i sqlite`

Comment: That seems to be the case. See the edit in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If your code neither throw an exception nor error, that means your PDO driver is not installed, down, disabled or some other reason not available.

It is always a good practice to added the following code before your PDO code to ensure you have PDO installed and it is running:

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME'))
    echo 'PDO driver unavailable';
```